# call a function written in iOS module from titanium

Tags: objective-c, xcode, titanium-alloy

in Xcode viewProxy i wrote the code below:

```
-(void) hideSelectedDate
{
NSLog(@"[INFO] in hide selected date proxy");
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideSelectedDate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

when i call it from titanium, i get "in hide selected date proxy" written in the console, but the app crashes after it.

how can i properly use :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideSelectedDate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

"hideSelectedDate" that i am trying to call in in the view

Comment: Can you share crash report? Device logs? anything to work with? :)

Comment: how to get the crash log? or device log

Comment: In the device, navigate to General -> About -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostic & Usage Data OR Open the Xcode Organizer window, find your device in the left sidebar, then select “device logs”

Comment: i'am running the app on an emulator and there is no ' Diagnostics & Usage' in about

Comment: Do you get any error? If yes, share it with us